# HTML img within a tag is still not clickable

Tags: html, css

```
<figure>
<a href="eternity-ring.html"><img src="eternity-ring.png" width="10%" alt="Trulli" style="width:100%"></a>
<figcaption>eternity ring</figcaption>
</figure>
```

I put an "a" attribute  that should make the picture clickable so that it'll lead me to another page.
the thing is that its not fully clickable, and only the left side can be clicked but I want that all of the image'll be clickable. can somebody help me please?

(BTW here is the CSS of it)

```
figure {
padding: none;
margin: auto;
margin-left: 11px;
width: 10%;
float: left;
text-align: none;
direction: rtl;
}
```

It works only when I delete the `float: left;` but I need it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: This sounds very much like a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: The should be outside, so I mean wrapping the figure. Do you really want to use float?

Comment: the `float` is necessary because I need to put more than one `img` in the same line

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `figcaption` to be clickable then you should put it inside `<a></a>` tag. Or, wrap whole `figure` with `<a></a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `float`, you can use `display: inline-block`, which will also allow you to place several elements on one line / horizontally next to each other. (also use the `vertical-align` parameter in this case, best probably set to `top`)

Answer (score 0):

If you also apply `float: left;` to the anchor inside the `figure`, it works.

I added a red border and a pointer to it just to make it obvious. And I removed the [invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) `text-align: none;`, which is useless anyway.

```css
figure {
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 11px;
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
/*   text-align: none; */
  direction: rtl;
}

figure a{
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <a href="eternity-ring.html"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" width="10%" alt="Trulli" style="width:100%"/></a>
  <figcaption>eternity ring</figcaption>
</figure>
```